# ANGULARJS $cookieStore and SessionId

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I am new to Anguarjs and I am writing a mobile application that needs to capture the SessionId after authentication.

I am using $ccoikestore in the application to store other data.

How do I capture the SessionId to be used later?

This is part of my Authentication Service:

```
/* Authentication Service
**********************************/

(function(){ 
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('Authentication')


app.factory('AuthenticationService',
['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'alertsManager',
function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, alertsManager) {
    var service = {};

    service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

        /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
         ----------------------------------------------*/
                //$timeout(function(){
        //  var response = { IsAuthenticated: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
        //      if(!response.IsAuthenticated) {
        //      alertsManager.addAlert('Username or password is incorrect', 'alert-danger');
        //    }
        //    callback(response);
        //}, 1000);

        /* Use this for real authentication
         ----------------------------------------------*/
                    $http.post('http://apps.laticrete.com/LSCWebApiService/lscapi/Session/Login', {username: username, password: password})
                        .success(function (response) {
                            if(!response.IsAuthenticated) {
                            alertsManager.addAlert('Username or password is incorrect', 'alert-danger');
                        }
           callback(response);
        });


    };

    service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
        var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
                password: authdata,
                            }
        };

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; 
        $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
    };

    service.ClearCredentials = function () {
        $rootScope.globals = {};
        $cookieStore.remove('globals');
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
    };

    return service;
}]);

app.factory('Base64', function () {

var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

return {
    encode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
                keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc4);
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    },

    decode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
        var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
        if (base64test.exec(input)) {
            window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                "Expect errors in decoding.");
        }
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        do {
            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    }
};

});


})();
```

And there is an Index:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {

        // Keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};

        if($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
        }
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
            // Redirect to login page if not logged in
            if($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });


        $rootScope.appVersion = '1.0.0';

        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }]);
```

My Authentication CTRL:

/* Authentication Controller
 *************************************/

(function(){
    'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('Authentication');

app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'cfpLoadingBar', 'alertsManager', '$modal',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService, cfpLoadingBar, alertsManager, $modal) {

    // Reset login status
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

    $scope.login = function() {
        cfpLoadingBar.start();
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
            if(response.IsAuthenticated) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                alertsManager.clearAlerts();
                $location.path('/jobs');
            } else {
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
            }
        });
    };

    // Modal Instance
    $scope.animationsEnabled = false;

    $scope.open = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '../modules/authentication/login.modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        });
    };

    $scope.imageSrc="img/img_pumpTruck.png";

    }]);
```

})();

console:

----------------------------------------------*/
                        $http.post('http://apps.laticrete.com/LSCWebApiService/lscapi/Session/Login', {username: username, password: password})
                            .success(function (response) {
                                if(!response.IsAuthenticated) {
                                alertsManager.addAlert('Username or password is incorrect', 'alert-danger');
                            }
                            $cookies.put('SessionId');
               callback(response);
            });

```
    };

    service.SetCredentials = function (username, password, SessionId) {
        var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);


        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('SessionId') || {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
                password: authdata,
                                    SessionId: $cookies.get('SessionId')
                            }
        };
```

Comment: I also have a index file:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $cookies, [$cokieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) service has been deprecated:

- Save object to cookie:

  $cookies.putObject('user', user);
- Get object from cookie:

  $rootScope.user = $cookies.getObject('user');
- Delete object:

  $cookies.remove('user');
- If you want you could add the object to the root scope after checking if the cookie is full:

  ```
  $rootScope.user = $cookies.getObject('user') || {
  user_id: '',
  session_id: ''
  };
  ```

Comment: Would I add this to service.SetCredentials = function ?

Comment: You could, it could also be after a successfull service.Login.  If you want, you can also have the object copied to the root scope, will update answer

Comment: I have added a controller and the index file to the original request. Like I said, im new to this and any help would be great.

Comment: I think you are in the right path, the cookie should be filled in the auth service

Comment: $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
                password: authdata,
                                    SessionId: SessionId
                            }
        }; would not work i guess since in   service.SetCredentials function you only pass username and password values, I dont see where SessionId is in your code

Comment: How would I make this to work then with the current code that I have?